# Background Location Update using Flutter and Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Is There a way to Get Location Update of user in a flutter app (for both android and ios) while the app is not running or is in the background (on stop state). Can this be done using dart code only? or if there is any other way to have this functionality?

Comment: any update on this post ?

Comment: You can try out this sample example (WIP) : https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/wiki/Background-Location-Updates

Answer (score 1):

There are a few pub libraries you could use.

[carp_background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location) is my favorite. It is build on top of [background_locator](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator) library. It is very easy to use, and seems to work fine on android. It claims to work on ios but i have not tested that.

It also shows a notification, and you can set the text for that.

Comment: it is a great library. But I am having an issue, i can't understand how do i access the location data when the app is terminated. i can see the data updating in the notification panel but that data is updating from a kotlin file. how do i access it in dart file

Comment: Probably open a new question about this.

Comment: Also it must be noted that it is now almost 4 years later and there are new packages that do the same thing but better.

Comment: can you name some?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/background_location